# How to prompt user for text input in Alert view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4

I am writing a section of code where it would be best if I could use a pop up box something like UIAlertView and prompt the user to enter text like a password.
Any pointers on an elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The best way that I've found to do this is to follow this tutorial: http://junecloud.com/journal/code/displaying-a-password-or-text-entry-prompt-on-the-iphone.html

[image]

The code used to achieve this is (taken directly from that great tutorial):

```
UIAlertView *passwordAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Server Password" message:@"\n\n\n"
delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel",nil) otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"OK",nil), nil];

UILabel *passwordLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12,40,260,25)];
passwordLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16];
passwordLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
passwordLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
passwordLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
passwordLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,-1);
passwordLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
passwordLabel.text = @"Account Name";
[passwordAlert addSubview:passwordLabel];

UIImageView *passwordImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"passwordfield" ofType:@"png"]]];
passwordImage.frame = CGRectMake(11,79,262,31);
[passwordAlert addSubview:passwordImage];

UITextField *passwordField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(16,83,252,25)];
passwordField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];
passwordField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
passwordField.secureTextEntry = YES;
passwordField.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
passwordField.delegate = self;
[passwordField becomeFirstResponder];
[passwordAlert addSubview:passwordField];

[passwordAlert setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,109)];
[passwordAlert show];
[passwordAlert release];
[passwordField release];
[passwordImage release];
[passwordLabel release];
```

Comment: Remove the image, and the font and backgroundColor assignments.
Add passwordField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;

Comment: [passwordAlert setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,109)]; is obsolete.

Comment: It's really good to know that this can be done but xcoder's answer is much better for iOS 5 and up...

Answer (score 117):

Things are much simpler in iOS 5, just set the alertViewStyle property to the appropriate style (UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput, UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput, or UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput). Example:

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Password" message:@"Enter your password:" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
alertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput;
UITextField *passwordTextField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
[alertView show];
```

Answer (score 28):

[image]> Simple You can apply like this

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Filename" message:@"Enter the file name:" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
alertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
UITextField *passwordTextField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
[alertView show]
```

Answer (score 6):

If my app was not to be released for yet a months or two, then I would login to http://developer.apple.com, look at the iOS 5 beta area, and see if `UIAlertView` might have something in store for us.

Answer (score 3):

I think it would be helpful to know that UIAlertView is not modal so the alert will not block.

I ran into this problem where I wanted to prompt the user for input then continue and then use that input in the code after. But instead the code after the [alert show] would run first until you reached the end of the run loop then the alert would display.

Answer (score 1):

Optimized code:

```
UIAlertView *passwordAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Password"
                                                        message:@"Please enter the password:\n\n\n"
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel",nil)
                                              otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"OK",nil), nil];

UITextField *passwordField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(16,83,252,25)];
passwordField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
passwordField.secureTextEntry = YES;
passwordField.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
passwordField.delegate = self;
[passwordField becomeFirstResponder];
[passwordAlert addSubview:passwordField];

[passwordAlert show];
[passwordAlert release];
[passwordField release];
```