# How can i ask user to enter username and password using a prompt in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, authentication, prompt

I want to let user enter the username and password without having to use a UIviewcontroller. How can i send the username and password from the alert prompt to the https server using a post request?

Comment: There are several approaches to add `UITextField` in `UIAlertView`. iOS 5 provides a simple way to do so (Google it), while iOS has to add subview to `UIAlertView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform Promtbox by using UIAlertVuew.

here is a post it will help You, check my post.

[How to prompt user for text input in Alert view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015842/how-to-prompt-user-for-text-input-in-alert-view/10892922#10892922)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe u can try DDAlertView [here](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/ddalertprompt)